# ImageView not updating with bitmap?

Tags: android

why my imageview is not updating in the for loop,only the image from last url is showing in the imageview not all the images,what i am doing wrong?

```
public class LoadImageActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView image_view;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    String[] imageLocation={
            "http://wallbase1.org/thumbs/rozne/thumb-499842.jpg",
            "http://ns3002439.ovh.net/thumbs/rozne/thumb-2493796.jpg",
            "http://ns3002439.ovh.net/thumbs/rozne/thumb-2486664.jpg" };  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        image_view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            bitmap = loadImage(imageLocation[i]);
            image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoadImageActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
            findViewById(R.id.imageview).startAnimation(rotate);
        }
    }

    public  Bitmap loadImage(String image_location){
        URL imageURL = null;
        try {
            imageURL = new URL(image_location);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = HttpURLConnection)imageURL.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);//Convert to bitmap
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at first, how slow is you device that you would switch between images in two successing lines of code (effectively)?

Secondly, the system has to be layouted first which happens after `onCreate()` returns. What you did is:

```
-set reference to bitmap that will be shown when layouted
-changed that reference
-let the system do the layout (Question: Which reference will be read?)
```

It looks like you want to set the first bitmap, rotate it and then set the other bitmap.
What you need to do is:

```
-set bitmap
-start animation with an Animation.AnimationListener, which sets the second bitmap in onAnimationEnd().
```

@Thanks to Adam!

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `Animation.AnimationListener` on your first animation, and you can load the next image and start the new transition in the `onAnimationEnd(...)` method of the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the underlying object (Bitmap) and then updating the ImageView.

Answer (score -1):

The method `loadImage()` is not in UI main Thread, use a Handler to update the ImageView with your new image.

Comment: wrong. it's called from onCreated, which is called from UI Thread on Activity creation time.